# Difference between rest and remainder

Tags: word-choice

What is the general difference between the words 'rest' and 'remainder'?

Comment: Both (taking just the relevant homonym of _rest_) have quite a few meanings; 'remainder' has some rather more specialist senses. Looking at just one situation where there is an obvious choice: _The rest of the day_ is the normal, unmarked expression. _The remainder of the day_ sounds either more formal or serious - or just more pretentious. Care should be taken to keep to Orwell's second rule unless one has a good reason not to. Perhaps 'the remainder of the holidays' and 'the rest of the holidays' suggest different things - one week remaining, and three occasional days left this year.

Comment: The only difference is that lawyers like to use them both in special phrases like _the rest, residue, and remainder_, just in case there **might** be some differnence.

Answer (score 2):

The word "remainder" **can** be used as a synonym for "rest" ("We finished the remainder of last night's stew").  However "remainder" also has certain specific meanings, and is more commonly used in those contexts.

Math: the leftover portion following a division operation.  43 divided by 10 equals 4 with a **remainder** of 3.

Publishing: a book sold at a discount (usually a work that's losing popularity).

Answer (score 1):

We rest in bed, and remain in bed, but we do not remainder in bed. A seller of goods can sell the rest or the remainder, but a seller of services can do neither. We can offer the rest of something or equally offer the remainder of the rest.